# IIS display standard yellow page instead of custom error page defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have defined custom error pages in IIS (i.e for http status code 500) and they are working if I return status code 500 from controller. But if there is unhandled exception in application iis displays standard yellow page with status code 500. So I'd expect IIS to display my custom error page but it's not happening.

Is there any way to force IIS to display custom error page on exception?

Comment: Check your web config, you will need to turn debug mode off and enable custom pages here. Microsoft has good documentation on this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: As i said error pages displays correctly if i return 500 from server but not on exception.

Comment: Is debug off explicitly?

Comment: what do you mean by debug? Setting mode to off? It displays full yellow page with stack trace and this is not what i want. I have custom error page defined in IIS.

Comment: Here is the Microsoft documentation for enabling/disabling debug, you will need it off in order to show your custom pages as you will get a stack trace otherwise https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should add this into the `web.config` into `<system.web>` section:

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/path/to/error">
   <error statusCode="413" redirect="~/path/to/error" />
   ...
   ...
</customErrors>
```

My advice is to do this only for the production environment, because the "yellow page" is extremely useful in dev mode to identity errors (for example you can add it only into web.release.config).

Comment: As i said i have custom error pages defined on IIS (I assume it's the same as configuring customErrors in web.config) and they work when i return 500 from server but not if unhandled exception is thrown.

Comment: IIS error pages are different from application error pages. If you get an exception, the ASP.NET pipeline will redirect you to the yellow page, not to the IIS standard error page. Thats why you can see the error text, the stack trace, ecc. You need to use the web.config to change this behavior for the app you are working on. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside `<system.webServer>` add

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/somePage.html" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: Is defining httpErrors different to defining error pages on IIS?

Comment: Does this [article](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/5/custom-404-and-error-pages-for-asp-net-and-static-files/) gives you a brief overview?

Comment: setting httpErrors for 500 does not display error page on unhandled exception.